# Bootstrap modal is not working

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to use Bootstrap modal.
I have imported bootstrap-modal.js

I need to trigger the modal using button attribute not JS.

Here is my code which doesn;t allow the modal to work !

```
<!-- Button to trigger modal -->
<a href="#myModal" role="button" class="btn" data-toggle="modal">Launch demo modal</a>

<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
    <h3 id="myModalLabel">Modal header</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <p>One fine body…</p>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your code is working perfectly . You should also include Jquery into your page. Add this before importing bootstrap.js

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
```

Also don't forget to link with bootstrap css file in the head section.

```
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
```